# how to connect/disconnect modem with command line (windows)?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, modem

I can connect/disconnect an ethernet card (or any card) with:

```
netsh interface set interface name="realtel" admin=enabled
```

[image]

I would like to do the same with a 3G key modem.
Unfortunatelly,

```
 netsh interface set interface name="3g" admin=enabled
```

says that the interface with "3g" is not regsitered by router.

**Any way to connect/dsiconnect it with command line ?**

I found that I can use to disconnect with

```
rasdial /disconnect
```

But how to connect ?

Answer (score 2):

```
rasdial 3g
```

It seems to work with my computer.

More about rasdial: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rasdial.mspx?mfr=true

Rasdial is not same as netsh, so rasdial commands don't work when using netsh at cmd. Rasdial command work at cmd and bat files.